# Qual a melhor alternativa para gravação de dados usando uma conexão 3G?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server

Tenho a seguinte situação: uma tabela de cabeçalho com os campos:

```
IDJOGO           
IDMODALIDADE
IDUSUARIO
VALOR_JOGADO
HORA_JOGO
```

E uma tabela de detalhe:

```
IDJOGO
NUMERO_JOGO
```

Neste caso, seria viável gravar o cabeçalho, fazer a recuperação do último ID gravado para o usuário e gravar os Itens ou seria melhor fazer uma *procedure* e deixar esta responsabilidade com o banco de dados?

Comment: @Ricardo, amigo, cliente servidor não tem 3G, é para fazer a gravação através de um celular, enviando os dados por uma Web API feita em C#

Comment: Celular = cliente, Web API (roda no servidor) = servidor. Apenas nomenclatura. Não tem nada de errado em usar procedure

Comment: @Ricardo, então você acha melhor fazer a criação da procedure porque pode acontecer algum problema de perder dados ou você tem outra justificativa? só para o entendimento melhor. agradeço!

Comment: apaguei tudo, falei besteira. Você pode sim criar a procedure, mas também pode fazer o seu servidor de aplicação fazer a jogada com ID. O que o celular tem que fazer é mandar tudo de uma vez para o servidor. Agora falei certo :)

Comment: @Ricardo ok! agradeço a ajuda!

Comment: E sobre a perda de dados, se o servidor de aplicação for fazer não existe perda, basta estar em transação.

Comment: @Ricardo, você quis dizer que ao enviar todos os dados, o processamento vai ser feito no Controller e desta forma não vai ter perda de dados.

Comment: Isso mesmo. E terá apenas uma chama ao servidor. Melhor cenário para o telefone, A API deve ter uma URL para receber todos eles.

Comment: @Ricardo, agora você me deu uma dica "pulo do gato" a api receber tudo junto, problema é saber quantos números vai ter no detalhe

Comment: @itasouza, só uma duvida.  sua aplicação vai rodar em um dispositivo móvel ?

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza , sim!

Comment: @itasouza, nesse caso o ideal é ter o web services para comunicação entre seu dispositivo e o banco de dados, no caso das suas tabelas o melhor é criar duas procedure uma para cada tabela pelo seguinte motivo, imagine que você vai gravar mais de um detalhe para cada cabeçalho (1 => N) então os parâmetros seria os mesmo para um novo detalhe.

Comment: Está usando Entity Framework ou ADO.NET?

Answer (score 2):

> Neste caso, seria viável gravar o cabeçalho, fazer a recuperação do último ID gravado para o usuário e gravar os Itens ou seria melhor fazer uma procedure e deixar esta responsabilidade com o banco de dados?

Se você está usando Entity Framework, não precisa fazer isso. Pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
var modalidade = db.Modalidades.FirstOrDefault();
var usuario = /* Recupere aqui seu usuário */
var cabecalho = new Cabecalho 
{
    Modalidade = modalidade,
    Usuario = usuario,
    ValorJogado = 10,
    HoraJogo = DateTime.Now,
    Detalhes = new List<Detalhe> 
    {
        new Detalhe { NumeroJogo = 3 }
    }
};
db.Cabecalhos.Add(cabecalho);
db.SaveChanges(); // Grava cabecalho e o detalhe automaticamente.
```

Por ADO.NET, possivelmente você terá que usar escopo transacional e comandar duas operações de inserção e uma seleção entre elas (trazer o registro de cabeçalho e definir a FK em detalhe).